# How do I unlock the secret room in Dungeon Defenders

Tags: dungeon-defenders

I beat all of the levels in Dungeon Defenders on mixed difficulties and the room upstairs isn't open, what do I need to do to open it?

Comment: To be clear, you're talking about [this one upstairs](http://dungeondefenders.wikia.com/wiki/Tavern_Easter_Egg) and not [this one on the ground floor](http://dungeondefenders.wikia.com/wiki/Tavern_Basement), correct?

Comment: Yes the one upstairs

Comment: @user72363 Mind editing the question a bit to make that more clear, then?